How do Catholics interpret the meaning of John 3:5 where Jesus says that in order to enter the kingdom of heaven a person has to be “born of water”?
I am trying to establish whether early church fathers such as Irenaeus and Justin Martyr understood the expression “born of water” in John 3:5 to mean water baptism. Are there any writings up to and including the ante-Nicene church fathers that support the view that a person has to be baptised in water in order to enter into the kingdom of heaven?
This article presents two views of what John 3:5 means. One is that “born of water” refers to physical birth and that is how Nicodemus interpreted the words of Jesus. He questioned how such a thing could happen to a grown person. Jesus said that a person had to be “born of water and the Spirit”.

The other perspective is that “born of water and the Spirit” refers to spiritual cleansing. The re-birth, or the new birth, which means to be “born again”, is a spiritual rebirth. Whereas people once-born have physical life, a person twice-born has eternal life (John 3:15–18, 36; 17:3; 1 Peter 1:23).

How does the Catholic Church interpret the expression “born of water”?

You’ve specified two different groups that you want answers from: the early church fathers and Catholics. Do you simply want Catholic interpretations of the early church fathers on the matter? Or do you want both? Water is a recurring theme in scripture used to wash away sin and guilt: Noah and the flood, Moses and the Sea of Reeds, the washing of hands when a dead body is discovered in the wilderness to cleanse the nearest town of the guilt of bloodshed, etc. Going back to creation and the flood, this also represents destruction (returning things to the state prior to creation) and recreation

@RyanPierceWilliams Forgive my ignorance, but I thought it was the Catholic Church who held to the writings of the church fathers. What I'm looking for are references to any writings from the early church fathers on this specific element (born by water) and if the Catholic Church accepts such views. I can ask a similar question of other denominations later, but what I don't want is to get into any "right or wrong" interpretations. Must dash - can get back to this later today...

Verses 14 and 15 of the same Jn 3 go on to state: "Just as Moses lifted up the snake in the wilderness, so the Son of Man must be lifted up,[f] 15 that everyone who believes may have eternal life in him.”[g

@KadalikattJosephSibichan This question is NOT asking what does a person have to do to have eternal life or to enter the kingdom of God. This question is asking what the Catholic Church believes the expression "born of water" means, and what documents the early church fathers may have written on this specific point.

That is right, Lesley. But I am afraid you are limiting the scope of the answer by detaching the words " and of the Holy Spirit " from Jn 3:5.

@KadalikattJosephSibichan - I am not asking about being born again. I am asking how the Catholic Church interprets the expression "born of water". Limiting the scope is deliberate because I seek a reference to what early church fathers may have said about the meaning of "born of water."

@Lesley Thank you for clarifying. The Church Fathers don’t belong to any given sect, but are a common heritage. I was raised Protestant and when I started college I bought myself the Ante-Nicene Fathers Series and started reading through all their writings because I was interested in Christology in the early church. My dad, who did his ordination process via the Church of the Nazarene, also had to study their writings aa part of the ordination process. In fact, Protestant belief in scripture as the primary source of truth is rooted in the early church, for that is what they debated from.

See catenabible. Com for Roman father's quotes

"Born of water" makes one share in the priesthood of Christ. Exodus19:6 is simple and clear, "The Kingdom of God is a Kingdom of Priesthood." Therefore, only a priest can enter the Kingdom of God. That's why all christian who claimed to be baptized outside the Church, cannot enter the Kingdom of God directly,m but must be purge in purgatory first. See my full answer below.


OP: Are there any writings up to and including the ante-Nicene church fathers that support the view that a person has to be baptised in water in order to enter into the kingdom of heaven?

First let's clear up the assumption that the Catholic Church and early church fathers taught all things identically.  They didn't, and in the water baptism question, we see the two only partially overlap.

694 Water. The symbolism of water signifies the Holy Spirit's action in Baptism, since after the invocation of the Holy Spirit it becomes the efficacious sacramental sign of new birth: just as the gestation of our first birth took place in water, so the water of Baptism truly signifies that our birth into the divine life is given to us in the Holy Spirit. As "by one Spirit we were all baptized," so we are also "made to drink of one Spirit."27 Thus the Spirit is also personally the living water welling up from Christ crucified28 as its source and welling up in us to eternal life.29 Catechism of the Catholic Church


1213 Holy [water] Baptism is the basis of the whole Christian life, the gateway to life in the Spirit (vitae spiritualis ianua),4 and the door which gives access to the other sacraments. Through Baptism we are freed from sin and reborn as sons of God; we become members of Christ, are incorporated into the Church and made sharers in her mission: "Baptism is the sacrament of regeneration through water in the word."5 -ibid-

So, the Catholic Church teaches "born of water" refers to water baptism.  It does not refer it to one's physical birth.
What about the early church fathers (emphasis mine)?

“And4854 dipped himself,” says [the Scripture], “seven times in Jordan.”4855 It was not for nothing that Naaman of old, when suffering from leprosy, was purified upon his being baptized, but [it served] as an indication to us. For as we are lepers in sin, we are made clean, by means of the sacred water and the invocation of the Lord, from our old transgressions; being spiritually regenerated as new-born babes, even as the Lord has declared: “Except a man be born again through water and the Spirit, he shall not enter into the kingdom of heaven.”4856 Irenaeus Fragment XXXIV

And then there is this from Justin Martyr.

Then they are brought by us where there is water, and are regenerated in the same manner in which we were ourselves regenerated. For, in the name of God, the Father and Lord of the universe, and of our Saviour Jesus Christ, and of the Holy Spirit, they then receive the washing with water. For Christ also said, “Except ye be born again, ye shall not enter into the kingdom of heaven.”1894 Now, that it is impossible for those who have once been born to enter into their mothers’ wombs, is manifest to all. Justin Martyr The First Apology Chapter LXI

Justin Martyr, however, goes on to say this in the same chapter.

And for this [rite] we have learned from the apostles this reason. Since at our birth we were born without our own knowledge or choice, by our parents coming together, and were brought up in bad habits and wicked training; in order that we may not remain the children of necessity and of ignorance, but may become the children of choice and knowledge, and may obtain in the water the remission of sins formerly committed, there is pronounced over him who chooses to be born again, and has repented of his sins, the name of God the Father and Lord of the universe; he who leads to the laver the person that is to be washed calling him by this name alone. -ibid-

With this we discern a difference between teachers of the early church and the subsequent Catholic Church that asserts the necessity of infant baptism; see CCC 1250.
Further, Tertullian understands John 3:5 to refer to water baptism and to informed choice.

It was from this circumstance [infant dedications to demons/gods] that the apostle said, that when either of the 220 parents was sanctified, the children were holy;1752 and this as much by the prerogative of the (Christian) seed as by the discipline of the institution (by baptism, and Christian education). “Else,” says he, “were the children unclean” by birth:1753 as if he meant us to understand that the children of believers were designed for holiness, and thereby for salvation; in order that he might by the pledge of such a hope give his support to matrimony, which he had determined to maintain in its integrity. Besides, he had certainly not forgotten what the Lord had so definitively stated:  “Except a man be born of water and of the Spirit, he cannot enter into the kingdom of God;”1754 in other words, he cannot be holy.
Tertullian A Treatise on the Soul Chapter XXXIX

Tertullian writes more about the necessity of water baptism here and answers a variety of objections.
So, to answer the OP, at least three early church fathers understand Jesus to be referring to water baptism, not physical birth.  The Catholic Church thus follows in their footsteps to a degree, interpreting John 3:5 as referring to water baptism, not physical birth with "water", but rejecting Paul's declaration at 1 Cor 7:14.

Appreciate the explanation and the quotes from Irenaeus, Justin Martyr and Tertullian.

What do you mean by the Church "rejecting Paul's declaration"?

@workerjoe explained in my answer

@SLM I can't see where you explain it.  What is your interpretation of 1 Cor 7:14?  Do you see it as supporting/opposing infant baptism?

The catechism in paragraph 1215 explicitly connects this quote from John to baptism:

1215 This sacrament is also called "the washing of regeneration and renewal by the Holy Spirit," for it signifies and actually brings about the birth of water and the Spirit without which no one "can enter the kingdom of God." (Titus 3:5; Jn 3:5)

https://www.vatican.va/archive/ENG0015/__P3H.HTM

Thank you for that link, which I have been exploring. Are there any writings up to and including the ante-Nicene church fathers that support the view that a person has to be baptised in water in order to enter into the kingdom of heaven?

Catholic Church teaches "baptismal priesthood", and a baptized person becomes a royal priest, a prophet and a king.

The Catechism of the Catholic Church tells us that “by Baptism, (the baptized) share in the priesthood of Christ, in his prophetic and royal mission” (CCC, 1268). This baptismal priesthood, also called the common priesthood, is founded on the sacrament of baptism.


The sacramental character conferred on those who receive this sacrament empowers them to participate in the Paschal Mystery, the dying and rising of Jesus, through the Eucharist and the other sacraments.


https://catholicphilly.com/2010/01/features/year-of-the-priest/called-to-participate-understanding-baptismal-and-ministerial-priesthood/#:~:text=This%20baptismal%20priesthood%2C%20also%20called,Eucharist%20and%20the%20other%20sacraments.

Why baptism is needed to enter the Kingdom of God?
Answer : Because the Kingdom of God is a Kingdom of Priesthood.
Furthermore, the Catholic Church teaches,

The Catechism of the Catholic Church is clear about the priestly office.


Baptism makes us members of the Body of Christ. … “to be a holy priesthood” (1 Peter 2:5). By Baptism they share in the priesthood of Christ, in his prophetic and royal mission. They are “a chosen race, a royal priesthood, a holy nation, God’s own people …” (1 Peter 2:9). Baptism gives a share in the common priesthood of all believers (CCC, 1267, 1268).


(Note: The Catechism also references the common priesthood in paragraphs 1141, 1143, 1268, 1305, 1535, 1547, 1591, and 1592.)

But, what is the difference between, Catholic Church and Protestant Baptism and other denominations and non-denominational baptism?
All of them have no "chrism oil", that conferred the full anointing of a royal priesthood, a prophet and a king.

Upon witnessing the Baptism of my first grandchild, I once again heard the threefold description in our call to holiness. After the Baptism comes the anointing with sacred chrism oil, wherein the priest or deacon prays these words:


As Christ was anointed Priest, Prophet, and King, so may you live always as a member of his body, sharing everlasting life.


This anointing is a stirring reminder of the sublime dignity conferred on us. We, too, must embrace these shared offices of priest, prophet, and king.
https://www.catholicdigest.com/from-the-magazine/from-the-catechism/priest-prophet-and-king-who-me/

How about "born of water"?
Catholic Church teaches that all the baptized are the children of Mary in the order of grace, and "water" symbolizes the water in the womb of Mary.

"All the elect are in the womb of Mary."- Montfort

Mary is the Mother of all the baptized, and the one who gave birth to the Church, the Body of Christ.
Water pointed to Hebrew name of Mary, as St.Jerome translated the word "Miryam" to means, "drop of the sea".

The first that’s always intrigued me is the title of Mary, Star of the Sea. The Catholic Encyclopedia mentions that this title of Mary originated from St. Jerome’s fifth century translation of Eusebius of Caesarea’s Onomasticon (dictionary of proper names) in which he translates Mary’s name in Hebrew— Miryam, meaning drop of the sea—into the Latin Stilla Maris, which later became Stella Maris due to a dialect of the Latin peasants.
https://www.catholicmom.com/articles/2014/05/05/why-do-we-call-mary-star-of-the-sea

How about born of water and spirit?
We can see this in Genesis1:2, in order to form Jesus Christ the incarnated Logos, two things are needed "water" and the Holy Spirit must hover the water. This passage symbolizes or described the mystery of incarnation, as when Jesus was not yet formed in the womb, the earth is still void, because everything was created for Jesus, and Jesus must be created first in the volition of God, outside of time.
If Jesus existed outside of time, before creation time begins, then, we can also see that the "water", the "water in the womb" described, that Mary or Miryam existed also, in the volition of God, outside of time. That's why Mary's dignity is higher that all the Heavenly Host combined, because, She existed in the heart of God, before creation time begins, while Jesus existed in the bosoms of the Father.
"Born of water and Spirit" signifies a "New Beginning", just like in Genesis1:2, and in Noah's time, after the storm seizes, a "dove hovering the water" signifies a new beginning. Likewise, when Jesus have to start His Redemptive Mission, the water in Jordan River, and the Holy Spirit in the form of a dove descended upon Jesus Christ.
How about in the Upper Room?
Mary or Miryam was there, symbolizing "water", and the Holy Spirit descended upon the Blessed Virgin Mary.
Again, we can see the wisdom behind St.Lousi De Montfort saying,

"All the elect are in the womb of Mary."-Montfort

In closing, Mary or Miryam is the "water" and the "Spirit" the Holy Spirit, cannot be separated in forming and giving new life or new beginning.
Mary is the Mother of All the baptized in the order of grace. that's the agonzing Jesus Christ at the Foot of the Cross, commanded us, as if saying, if you want to born again, you must...

"Behold thy Mother."-John19:27

Because Jesus promised us, "I will not leave you orphan..."
Msry is the Mother of all the baptized in the order of grace. -CCC967

She is our Mother in the order of grace...-967


https://marian.org/mary/in-the-catechism#:~:text=she%20is%20our%20Mother%20in,model%20of%20faith%20and%20charity.

A true Christian, is not an orphan, because, a true Christian, is born in the waters in the womb of Mary, the waters in the womb that the Holy Spirit hovers to form a new life.
Those who claimed to be Christian, but do not acknowledge the spiritual truth, that one needed a spiritual Mother is a fake christian, as St.Montfort teaches, that these type of Christian is a fake Christian, and their Father is the devil.

If he prides himself on having God for his Father but does not give to Mary the tender affection of a true child, he is an impostor and his father is the devil.


https://www.montfort.org.uk/Writings/SM.php

